# What did Rey and Chewie tell Luke about Han's destiny?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, luke-skywalker, rey, han-solo

In *The Last Jedi*, Jedi Master Luke Skywalker first refused to talk with Ray and only closed himself in his hut. Rey went to get Chewbacca, who rammed in the hut door allowing her to restart the conversation.

> **Luke:** How did you find me?
>
> **Rey:** Long story. We'll tell you on the Falcon.
>
> **Luke:** Falcon?
>
> (Chewie growls softly)
>
> **Luke:** Wait. Where's Han?

What did Rey and Chewie exactly tell Luke about what had happened to Han, more than he was dead, and murdered by his own son? The movie does not reveal this at all, but maybe it's detailed in other media. Did they tell him about the mission on Starkiller Base, the reunion of Han and Leia, or other background information?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rey gives Luke a potted history of Han's death as well as running through her own personal story. She also explains the current tactical position of the Resistance and the disposition of the First Order's forces and their tactical supremacy.

> *The twin suns of Ahch-To bathed the village in the soft gold of afternoon. But the warm light gave little comfort to the three people seated outside the huts, especially Rey. **The story she had begun with how she befriended Finn turned into tragedy as she revealed Kylo Ren’s murder of his own father and her mentor.**
>
>   “Han Solo was my friend,” she said.
>
>   It was obvious Han had been the same to Luke Skywalker, even if they hadn’t seen each other in years. The Jedi Master appeared shaken. Sitting next to him, Chewbacca moaned.
>
>   **Rey returned to the purpose of her visit. “Leia showed me projections of the First Order’s military. It’s massive, and now that the Republic is destroyed, there’s nothing to stop them. They will control all the major systems within weeks.** They’ll destroy the Resistance, Finn, everyone I care about. Will you help us?*
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: A Junior Novel](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_A_Junior_Novel)</sup></sub>